# Custom variable pass to JS callback

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, node-modules

I have two variable to pass to JS callback function, one derived from main function. Another one is randomly given inline. check below example JS code,

```
function main(callback) {
 st = "mainString"
 console.log("Execution:1 # Main function, string: " + st)
 callback(this.st)
}

function myCallback(st1, st2) {
 console.log("Execution:2 # callback function, st1: " + st1 + " st2: " + st2)
}

main(myCallback.bind({"st1" : this.st, "st2" :" ad-hoc"}))
```

Expected output would be below, so that both input parameters treated well and printed in order.

*Execution:1 # Main function, string: mainString*

*Execution:2 # callback function, st1: mainString st2: ad-hoc*

But i get this,

*Execution:1 # Main function, string: mainString*

*Execution:2 # callback function, st1: mainString st2: undefined*

Any help to get around this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
console.log("Execution:2 # callback function, st1: " + st1 + " st2: " + st2)
```

to

```
console.log("Execution:2 # callback function, st1: " + st1 + " st2: " + this.st2)
```

Example snippet

```js
function main(callback) {
 st = "mainString"
 console.log("Execution:1 # Main function, string: " + st)
 callback(this.st)
}

function myCallback(st1) {
 console.log("Execution:2 # callback function, st1: " + st1 + " st2: " + this.st2)
}

main(myCallback.bind({"st1" : this.st, "st2" :" ad-hoc"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

When using bind with object literal as parameter you should specify the context on your function.
On your condition, you can simply just add this keyword to your st2 in you **myCallback** function as following:

```js
function myCallback(st1, st2) {
    console.log("Execution:2 # callback function, st1: " + st1 + " st2: " + this.st2)
}
```

hope it helps